# WCF stopped generating Silverlight classes after Azure SDK update

Tags: azure

I recenlty update to Azure SDK 1.8, But generated code file contains such errors :

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Gets the context that is registered as a lifetime object with the current application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> is thrown if there is no current application,
    /// no contexts have been added, or more than one context has been added.
    /// </exception>
    /// <seealso cref="System.Windows.Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects"/>
    public new static WebContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            return ((WebContext)(WebContextBase.Current));
        }
    }
```

Jalal

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution for now. Add the following code to app.config and web.config :

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.7.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ServiceBus" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.6.0.0" newVersion="1.7.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="101.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.4655.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: But still i am facing some issues when upload to Azure. I got errors like this :